# can draggable item becomes droppable after drop?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, draggable, droppable

I'm using jqueryui. I have draggable item and droppable area. When i drop item into droppable area, dropped item should be droppable. Is it possible?

Comment: This question doesn't make sense! What are you trying to do?

Comment: Makes perfect sense...Nested droppable containers. Drag an item in, then when it exists in the "master" container, the new child is also capable of being a parent to future children. I'm working on this right now actually and while it's reasonably straightforward, there are some gotcha with positioning

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Please take a look at this [JQFAQ.com](http://jqfaq.com/can-draggable-item-becomes-droppable-after-drop/) topic, this will help you to change the draggable item as droppable after it dropped. There are few more FAQs too.

I have put comments to understand the codes.

Comment: I would look to ensure that I answered your question correctly. I am assuming that when you drop B over A, you want B to become droppable and A should not be droppable anymore. Could you confirm that this is your requirement?

Comment: When i drop B over A, i want B to become droppable. Also A still be droppable too.

Comment: But your example is helped me.